# Remove querystring value on page refresh

Tags: php

I am redirecting to a different page with Querystring, say

```
header('location:abc.php?var=1');
```

I am able to display a message on the redirected page with the help of querystring value by using the following code, say

```
if (isset ($_GET['var']))
{

    if ($_GET['var']==1) 
    {
        echo 'Done';
    }
}
```

But my problem is that the message keeps on displaying even on refreshing the page. Thus I want that the message should get removed on page refresh i.e. the value or the querystring should not exist in the url on refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot "remove a query parameter on refresh". "Refresh" means the browser requests the same URL again, there's no specific event that is triggered on a refresh that would let you distinguish it from a regular page request.

Therefore, the only option to get rid of the query parameter is to redirect to a different URL after the message has been displayed. Say, using Javascript you redirect to a different page after 10 seconds or so. This significantly changes the user experience though and doesn't really solve the problem.

Option two is to save the message in a server-side session and display it once. E.g., something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

This *can* cause confusion with parallel requests though, but is mostly negligible.

Option three would be a combination of both: you save the message in the session with some unique token, then pass that token in the URL, then display the message once. E.g.:

```
if (isset($_GET['message'], $_SESSION['messages'][$_GET['message']])) {
    echo $_SESSION['messages'][$_GET['message']];
    unset($_SESSION['messages'][$_GET['message']]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Better use a session instead

Assign the value to a session var

```
$_SESSION['whatever'] = 1;
```

On the next page, use it and later unset it

```
if(isset($_SESSION['whatever']) && $_SESSION['whatever'] == 1) {
  //Do whatever you want to do here

  unset($_SESSION['whatever']); //And at the end you can unset the var
}
```

This will be a safer alternative as it will save you from sanitizing the get value and also the value will be hidden from the users

Answer (score 2):

There's an elegant JavaScript solution. If the browser supports history.replaceState (http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) you can simply call window.history.replaceState(*Object*, *Title*, *URL*) and replace the current entry in the browser history with a clean URL. The querystring will no longer be used on either refresh or back/previous buttons.

Answer (score 1):

When the message prompt ask for a non exsisting session. If false, show the message, if true, do nothing. session_start(); is only needed, if there is no one startet before.

```
session_start();
if ($_GET['var']==1 && !isset($_SESSION['message_shown'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['message_shown'] = 1;
    echo 'Done';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way [Using Sessions]

```
<?php
//abc.php
session_start();
if (isset ($_GET['var']))
{
if ($_GET['var']==1) 
{
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
{
//$_SESSION['views']=1;
}
else
{
    echo 'Done';
   $_SESSION['views']=1;
}
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the question mean something like this?

```
 $uri_req = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
      $new_uri_req = str_replace('?avar=1', '?', $uri_req);
      $new_uri_req = str_replace('&avar=1', '', $new_uri_req);
      $pos = strpos($new_uri_req, '?&');
      if ($pos !== false) {
       $new_uri_req = str_replace('?&', '?', $new_uri_req);
      } 
     }

if( strrchr($new_uri_req, "?") == '?' ){
 $new_uri_req = substr($new_uri_req, 0, -1);
}

 
     echo $new_uri_req; exit;
```

You can use then the url to redirect without vars. You can also do the same in js.

str_replace() can pass array of values to be replaced. First two calls to str_replace() can be unified, and filled with as many vars you like that needs to be removed. Also note that with preg_replace() you can use regexp that can so manage any passed var which value may change. Cheers!

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to me that no one answer was resolving what asked in the question